# Get a list of back links to my website in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, backlinks, reporting

I want to know the list of URLs that link to my site. Is it possible with Google Analytics?

I want a report with the list of links that are most used.

Answer (score 2):

In Google Analytics pick Acquisition from the Sidebar Menu, then All Traffic, then Referrals.

To get the specific page that had the link, add a secondary dimension of Referral Path

Answer (score 0):

If there is traffic coming to your site through links which is also called referrer is stored in your server log for every hit. you just need right tool or language such awk to parse that data.

You can try with [Awstats](http://www.awstats.org/), note: I didn't tried it for now.

Comment: But the referer is optional there is no http request..  [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88481/what-causes-an-empty-referrer-field-in-a-webserver-log-file).

Answer (score 0):

While referral traffic in GA is a good way to understand links, I would recommend relying on Google search console's back link report as a better way to understand links